# Magento 1.9.4 cart issue

Tags: magento-1.9.4

Magento 1.9.4 - I can add simple and configurable items to the cart, but in the cart configurable items are showing but simple items not showing, any suggestion?

Comment: any error on console or log files?

Comment: No error showing, 
in cart.phtml $this->getItemHtml($_item); is not working for simple products, but working for configurable items, strange error!